# Updated contract with increased PTO days; how to adjust them for the remainder of the year?

Tags: vacation, contract-extension

I've received an updated contract that now includes paid vacation, where before I didn't have such a thing (previously had a week of unpaid vacation expected per year).

Now, I'm going to ask how this is to be applied to the current year, but I was curious about what the standard/expected way this is handled.

For example, would this likely be prorated for the remainder of the year? I.e., having 10 paid leave days would come out to ~2 days (since there are 66 days left in the year)?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere of course, and as I said I certainly intend to ask, but I was curious as to if there was a norm for this type of thing

Comment: Which country is this in as not havng any paid vacation seems very odd.

Comment: @Mark, the US. They act like a startup (even though they're 20+ years old) in terms of how they handle employees and "contractors", but I'm young (never worked elsewhere, so I don't know better) and they pay well (so I maybe don't care as much)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, I'm going to ask how this is to be applied to the current year, but I was curious about what the standard/expected way this is handled.

Honestly, you don't need to know what is the "standard" way this is handled, you need to know how this is handled in *your* company.

You should **approach your boss and politely ask how this new contract applies**, and since when does it start counting for the vacations.

To answer you actual question, usually the year starts counting from the moment you get the new contract. This means that starting now you have 10 paid days off, that you can use anytime, and a year from now you will have another 10, etc.

However, you should ask your boss to be sure how this is going to apply, and how the unpaid vacations you have not spent will be handled.

Comment: This makes sense, both parts

Comment: Glad I could help :) welcome to The Workplace btw

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize it put the New contributor badge on users even being on SE for 7 years (even if it is another branch)

Comment: I think it was because this is your first post on TWP, regardless of you having >2k on other sites. The new contributor is per site thing as far as I know